# Как в Python создать свой неизменяемый класс?

Tags: python-3.x, классы

как сделать "настоящий" неизменяемый класс, чтобы в памяти создавался только один экземпляр с определенным значением. Например класс `int`:

```
int1 = int(0)
int2 = int(0)
print(f'int1 = {int1}, id(int1) = {id(int1)}')
print(f'int2 = {int2}, id(int2) = {id(int2)}')
```

выдает

```
int1 = 0, id(int1) = 2227523354832
int2 = 0, id(int2) = 2227523354832
```

Т.е. для значения "0" в памяти создается только один экземпляр класса int.
Возможно ли написать свой класс с такими свойством?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `int(0)` написать например `int('257')` — и экземпляры получатся разные

Comment: `int` в Питоне - [value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object). Маленькие значения кешируются и интерпретатор следит чтобы не было двух разных нулей например, большие значения могут существовать во многих экземплярах.

Comment: Вы можете создать свой собственный класс, в котором все значения будут хранится в каком-то словаре. Конструктор объекта придётся скрыть от пользователя, объекты будут создаваться фабрикой, которая будет поддерживать нужный вам порядок. То есть, вы вообще спрячете класс в глубине какого-то модуля. Или надо переопределить `__new__`.

Comment: ... а ещё есть метаклассы. Вот тут про синглетоны, но подходы близкие: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyClass:
    
    instances = {}
    
    def __new__(cls, x):
        if x in cls.instances:
            return cls.instances[x]
        obj = super().__new__(MyClass)
        cls.instances[x] = obj
        return obj


obj1 = MyClass(0)
obj2 = MyClass(0)

print(id(obj1))
print(id(obj2))
```

Comment: А как сборщик мусора будет к такому решению относиться?

Comment: @monteg179 А что сборщик мусора? Будут удаляться ссылки На объект, а не сам объект.

Comment: После выполнения `obj1 = MyClass(0)` в памяти создастся экземпляр класса и на него две ссылки, `obj1` и в `MyClass.instances{}`. И после того, как `obj1` станет недействительной (`del obj1` например) соответствующий экземпляр из памяти удален не будет. Разве это хорошо? Я только начал изучать Python, отсюда такие вопросы.

Comment: @monteg179 Ну да, всё так и будет. Но хорошо это или плохо - зависит от сценария использования. Если вы уверены, что вам такой объект в кэше больше точно никогда не понадобится - сделайте возможность в этом классе удаления объекта из кэша при вызове специально предназначенного для этого метода.

Comment: Все пошло не так я ожидал, потому что задал неправильный вопрос. Меня интересует само понятие "неизменяемость" - это условность или что-то конкретное(базовый класс, набор методов и т.д).
Возможно ли написать свой класс, который Python будет считать неизменяемым, или неизменяемыми считаются только классы `int`, `float`, `str`, `tuple` и т.д.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а аналога [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) в питоне нет? Вроде гугл что-то находит: [`WeakValueDictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary).

Comment: @monteg179, возможно, есть решение с нормальной сборкой мусора.

Answer (score -1):

А вообще я фигню написал. Например

```
int1: int = int('0')
int2: int = int(0)
print(f'int1 = {int1}, id(int1) = {id(int1)}')
print(f'int2 = {int2}, id(int2) = {id(int2)}')
```

Выдает

```
int1 = 0, id(int1) = 2298704822480
int2 = 0, id(int2) = 2298704822480
```

А вот другой пример

```
int1: int = int('123456789')
int2: int = int(123456789)
print(f'int1 = {int1}, id(int1) = {id(int1)}')
print(f'int2 = {int2}, id(int2) = {id(int2)}')
```

Выдает

```
int1 = 123456789, id(int1) = 1416526813040
int2 = 123456789, id(int2) = 1416526813264
```

Лажа какая-то ...

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Не лажа, а определённый диапазон целочисленных объектов создаётся питоном заранее для оптимизации. И все вновь создаваемые целые объекты из этого диапазона будут указывать на эти заранее созданные объекты.

Comment: Лажа в том, что мое утверждение про неизменяемые классы оказалось неверным. Это я облажался.